# Adding sheet permissions with notification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm currently using....

```
DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).addEditor(shareWith);
```

to set permissions programmatically on my shared spreadsheets.

One thing i noticed is that the shared user doesn't receive notification that the file is being shared with them.

Is there any parameter that I need to add to trigger that notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addEditor(user) and addEditor(emailAddress) methods of

- Class File from the Drive Service
- Class Spreadsheet from the Spreadsheet Service

haven't "any parameter to add to trigger that notification".

One alternative is to use Mail Service (MailApp) or the Gmail Service (GmailApp) to build and send your own notification as an email message.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet

Answer (score -1):

The script you shared does send the "Invitation to edit" notification email to the editor. Instead of using a parameter, you can use `DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).addEditor(emailAddress);` when you want to add an editor to a spreadsheet and send the notification email to the editor. You can use `SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID).addEditor(emailAddress);` when you want to add an editor to a spreadsheet without the notification email being sent to the editor.